# Laravel Many to Many relationship gets partial results

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I have Course and Category Models with many to many relationship between them. So I created CategoryCourse Model to decompose relationship. Here are my three models:

```
class CategoryCourse extends Model
{
   private $foreignkeys = [
     '$category_id','$course_id'
   ];

   public function categories()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
   }

   public function courses()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
   }
}

class Category extends Model
  {
   protected $title = ['title'];

   public function categorycourse()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryCourse');
   }
}

class Course extends Model
{

   protected $fillable = [
       'title', 'desc'
   ];

   public function categorycourse()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryCourse');
   }
}
```

In my controller I have method as follows:

```
public function getCoursesByCategory(Request $request, $id)
 {
   $id = Hashids::decode($id);
   $categories = Category::findOrFail($id[0]);
   $courses = $categories->categorycourse()->get();
   return view('courses',compact('courses'));
 }
```

I have three tables in database, they are categories, courses and category_courses. My view is displaying results from category_courses but not results from courses. I am learning laravel. Can any one please help? I want to display all courses that belong to a category, in my view.
Here is my view code:

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
  {{$course->title}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code to:

```
class Category extends Model
  {
   protected $title = ['title'];

   public function courses()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'category_course', 'category_id', 'course_id');
   }
}
```

The relationship should be in Category only.

And then you call:

```
$courses = $categories->courses;
```